# Fetching data from two queries as one

Tags: php, sql, pdo, inner-join

## This is a picture-type webpage

What i want to be returned is a string like this:
nameOfTag (numberOfUnratedElements)

I am using a system where the user only knows the filename of the image, and the rest is stored in two tables.

### Table info

#### table_name = images

- id (int) primaryKey
- filename (varchar255) unique
- pick (tinyint)
- reject (tinyint)

#### table_name = image_tags

- id (int) primaryKey
- filename (varchar255)
- tag_name (varchar255)

### Functionality

The program should get the filename of the image from the user, and get all tags associated with that filename. Afterwards the program should return the number of unrated (`pick = FALSE AND reject = FALSE`) images in each of the tags returned.

### Code

As of now I am using a loop to achieve this. ("$fname" is the filename of the image in the format {filename}.{extension})

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT image_tags.tag_name, images.filename FROM image_tags JOIN images ON image_tags.filename = images.filename WHERE images.filename = ? ORDER BY image_tags.tag_name");
$query->bindValue(1, $fname);
$query->execute();
foreach($query->fetchAll() as $tag){
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) as total, image_tags.tag_name, images.filename, images.pick, images.reject FROM image_tags JOIN images ON image_tags.filename = images.filename WHERE image_tags.tag_name = ? AND images.pick = FALSE AND images.reject = FALSE");
    $query->bindValue(1, $tag['tag_name']);
    $query->execute();
    print '<span style="display: block"><a style="display: inline-block" href=tag.php?tag=' . $tag['tag_name'] . '>' . $tag['tag_name'] . ' (' . $query->fetch()['total'] . ')</a></span>';
}
```

### Question

My question is if there is a way to achieve this without using the loop, or alternatively with just one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with more joins:

```
SELECT it.tag_name, i.filename, COUNT(i2.filename) as total,
       GROUP_CONCAT(i2.filename) as filenames
FROM image_tags it JOIN
     images i
     ON it.filename = i.filename LEFT JOIN
     image_tags it2
     ON it2.tag_name = it.tag_name LEFT JOIN
     images i2
     ON it2.filename = i2.filename AND
        i2.pick = FALSE AND i2.reject = FALSE
WHERE i.filename = ?
GROUP BY it.tag_name, i.filename
ORDER BY it.tag_name;
```

Note that `filenames` is a concatenated list of filenames.  I'm not sure if that is needed, and it might exceed the default length for `group_concat()` (1024 bytes).

Hmmm, I think you can simplify your first query and hence this query to:

```
SELECT it.tag_name, it.filename, COUNT(i2.filename) as total,
       GROUP_CONCAT(i2.filename) as filenames
FROM image_tags it LEFT JOIN
     image_tags it2
     ON it2.tag_name = it.tag_name LEFT JOIN
     images i2
     ON it2.filename = i2.filename AND
        i2.pick = FALSE AND i2.reject = FALSE
WHERE it.filename = ?
GROUP BY it.tag_name, i.filename
ORDER BY it.tag_name;
```

The first `images` reference isn't needed because all the needed data is in `image_tags`.

Comment: Just a small comment about your suggestion. I am guessing the "it" abbreviation is to the image_tags-table and the "i" abbreviation is to the images-table. What is the "i2" and "it2" abbreviation to?

Comment: @MathiasNervik . . . These are table aliases.  They are needed when queries have self-joins, as these queries do.  They distinguish between different references to the same table in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: That first bit of code works best, as the second one returns 0 rows ;)